# Spring-data the good way to configure and initialize database at run time

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.0.6 with Spring-Batch and Spring-Data.

The context is the following. I have a spring-batch job with differents steps:

- step 1: it generates with a .sh script on a remote machine, an in memory database
- step 2: it connects to the memory database
- step n: use database to retrive somes informations
- last step: it closes the database connection and removes it

Knowing that I would like to use JpaRepository to request my database, What is the the best way to connect in the database at the runtime and configure my repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You need not worry about opening/closing the connections. Spring batch JPA repository's methods would automatically open the transactions/connections and terminates once the jpa repository's methods are executed or when the spring batch terminates on error. Please enable jdbc trace logs to validate the opening and closing of transactions/connections to db.